# Left Join Sum not returning expected values

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that I'm joining, but the query sometimes matches in another row.

### Table t1

```
+-----+
| Re  |
+-----+
| 123 |
| 321 |
+-----+
```

### Table table2

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Re  | Re2 | Cla | Val |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 123 | abc | RV  |  10 |
| 123 | cba | AB  |   5 |
| 321 | xyz | ZV  |   4 |
| 321 | zyx | RV  |   6 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

### Query

```
 select t1.Re,t2.Re2, sum(t2.Importeenmonedalocal) as Sum, from table t1
 left join table2 as t2 on
 t2.Re LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.Re,'%') 
 group by t1.Re;
```

### Actual Result:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| Re  | Re2 | Sum |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 123 | cba |  15 |
| 321 | xyz |  10 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

### Expected Result:

What I expect is the join matches in t2 when `Cla='RV'` like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| Re  | Re2 | Sum |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 123 | abc |  15 |
| 321 | zyx |  10 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I tried to add a `where` like this:

```
 select t1.Re,t2.Re2, sum(t2.Importeenmonedalocal) as Sum, from table t1
 left join   table2 as t2  on
 t2.Re  LIKE CONCAT ('%',t1.Re,'%') 
 where t2.Cla='RV'
 group by t1.Re;
```

but the sum is incorrect:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| Re  | Re2 | Sum |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 123 | abc |  10 |
| 321 | zyx |   6 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: *im using this query to join the tables* This query is non-deterministic. For example - in 1st output row `t2.Re2` may be sometimes `'abc'`, sometimes `'cba'`..

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.Re,
       MAX( CASE WHEN t2.Cla='RV' THEN t2.Re2 END ) Re2,
       SUM( t2.Importeenmonedalocal ) `Sum`
FROM `table` t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Re LIKE CONCAT ('%',t1.Re,'%') 
GROUP BY t1.Re;
```